# Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've written a custom keras loss for `crf` loss computation.

```
def myLoss(self,y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Args:
        y_true: a tensor of shape batch_size X  num_labels 
        y_pred: a tensor of shape batch_size X seq_length X num_labels
        
    """
    with tf.init_scope():
        self.seqlen = tf.constant(self.batch_size, shape=(self.seq_length,))
    log_likelihood, transtion = tfa.text.crf.crf_log_likelihood(y_pred,y_true,self.seqlen )# logits, labels, seq_length
        loss = tf.reduce_sum(-log_likelihood)
    return loss
```

But above code raises the following:

```
ValueError: Tensor-typed variable initializers must either be wrapped in an init_scope or callable (e.g., `tf.Variable(lambda : tf.truncated_normal([10, 40]))`) when building functions. Please file a feature request if this restriction inconveniences you.
```

As per the error, I tried to wrap tensor computation with `init_scope`, but not sure if that is the correct way. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem but in a different context. Making the variable initializer callable worked for me.
Simply add a `lambda` before you call `self.seqlen` in your code like this and see if it works:

```
tfa.text.crf.crf_log_likelihood(y_pred, y_true, lambda: self.seqlen)
```